# Understanding the definition of continuity in real analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, definition

I'm reading the definition of continuity at a point from [Introduction to Real Analysis](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Introduction+to+Real+Analysis%2C+4th+Edition-p-9780471433316) by Bartle-Sherbert text.

"Real Analysis" definition of continuity:

> [image]

This seems a lot like the definition of "limits". Then I Google the definition of continuity and I see the following.

"Calculus" definition of continuity:
$$
\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c).
$$

Ah yes, this is the definition I remembered from Calculus. Very simple.

So, I'm guessing the two definitions are equivalent, and that the reason I'm reminded of a limit in the Analysis definition is because that is exactly what it is.

Why does the Real Analysis text go so far just to avoid saying that continuity at a point is a limit?

I understand the need for precise definitions, especially in defining a first principle concept such as limit. But now that we already have a rigorous definition of limit, why not just state the definition in terms of a limit?

Comment: This is the standard definition for a continuous function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The author chose to spell out the definition of the limit, possibly to make it self-contained. No objection, your honor.

Comment: How do you expect it to work out without defining it in the way it has been defined in Bartle? Honestly, by just "calculating" the limit and showing that it equals to the value of function at that point is not the purpose of analysis. The idea is to see what brings about these results.

Comment: I'd like to mention that from a pedagogical standpoint the "analysis" definition of continuity is more useful for teaching analysis students than the "intro to calculus" definition even though they are equivalent. The latter hides the complexity under nice notation which students may not appreciate because they think that they already understand what limits are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two definitions are equivalent.   If you expand out the definition of a limit into your second definition of continuity, then you get the first.    That doesn't mean the first one is crappy or that the textbook is bad.    It's just a difference in what the author chose to emphasize.

Comment: Actually the definitions are not *quite* equivalent. The $\epsilon$ definition also encompasses a special case which says that $f$ is continuous at $c$ if $c$ is an isolated point of $A$, in which case $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: Wouldn't x have to equal c in order for that to apply?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark    I think that if we use the $\epsilon - \delta $ definition of the limit, than $f=\{ {(a,b)}\} $ would have $\lim_{ x \to a} f(x) =b$ and so $f$ would be continuous as per the $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)= f(c)$ definition also.

Comment: I think this is so since for each $\epsilon $, we we could use any positive $\delta $ to prove the limit.

Comment: @DevashishKaushik: Well, it depends on your definition of limit, but I was thinking of the convention used (for example) in Rudin's *Principles*, where the value $f(a)$, even if it's defined, should *not* be taken into account when considering $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$. That is, the definition says “$0 < |x-a| < \delta$” instead of just “$|x-a| < \delta$” (which you can find in some other sources). And also $a$ needs to be an accumulation point of the domain of $f$ in this case.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark   I see. However what I meant was that si CE there is no $x$, any value if $delta $, would work for showing that $ 0 \lt \vert x-a \vert \lt \delta $ for every $x$ in the interval. However, I do see how your point about the nrrd for $a$ to be a cluster point negates that.

Comment: @DevashishKaushik: Yes, you need to assume that $a$ is not an isolated point in $D_f$. Since otherwise (with that “vacuously true” interpretation) your single-point function would satisfy $f(x) \to K$ as $x \to a$ for *any* number $K$, not just $K=f(a)$. And this breaks a lot of things; to begin with, you can't even talk about *the* limit anymore.

Answer (score 2):

One simply need to read the book more carefully.

Bartle and Sherbert state clearly **right after** the definition you quoted that

> As with the definition of limit, the definition of continuity at a point can be formulated very nicely in terms of neighborhoods. This is done in the next result. We leave the verification as an important exercise for the reader.
>
> [image]

And **right below** Theorem 5.1.2, the authors make the following **remark**:

> [image]

**All** of these are in the SAME page (page 125).

Reading carefully, slowly, and thoroughly helps.

Comment: I saw that after I posted the question. I thought my impatience went under the radar, but here you came 6 months later to set me straight.    

In my own defense, I'm in the next Real Analysis course at my school and I've become at least somewhat more patient. We are studying Lebesgue measure/integration and this stuff was so much simpler... :)    

Thank you for your comment.